# Linux kernel version mismatch

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module, archlinux

I'm trying to create a simple kernel module which makes the keyboard LEDs flashing. It works fine on Linux 3.16 (Ubuntu 14.04) but it doesn't change the LED status on 4.5 (Arch).

I can't figure out what kind of difference causes it, I didn't find anything useful in demsg. Any idea how could I find about this problem?

Code:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/device.h>
#include <linux/tty.h>
#include <linux/kd.h>
#include <linux/vt.h>
#include <linux/console_struct.h>
#include <linux/vt_kern.h>
#include "device.h"
#include "timer.h"

#define LEDS_ON 0x07
#define LEDS_OFF 0xFF

static int major_number;
static struct class *class;
static struct tty_driver *driver; 
static unsigned long led_status = LEDS_OFF;


static void timer_callbak(void)
{
    if (led_status == LEDS_OFF) {
        led_status = LEDS_ON;
    } else {
        led_status = LEDS_OFF;
    }

    driver->ops->ioctl(vc_cons[fg_console].d->port.tty, KDSETLED, led_status);
}

static long device_ioctl(struct file *file, unsigned int command, unsigned long argument)
{
    if (command == ON && led_status == LEDS_OFF) {
        timer_init(&timer_callbak);
    } else if (command == OFF && led_status == LEDS_OFF){
        timer_exit();
    } else if (command != OFF && command != ON) {
        printk(KERN_WARNING "Invalid ioctl() command");

        return -1;
    } 

    return 0;
}

static struct file_operations operations = {
        .unlocked_ioctl = device_ioctl
};

dev_t create_dev_type(void) 
{
    return MKDEV(major_number, 0);
}

void create_device(void)
{
    major_number = register_chrdev(0, NAME, &operations);
    printk("Keyboard leds registered with major_number \"%d\"", major_number);

    class = class_create(THIS_MODULE, NAME);
    device_create(class, NULL, create_dev_type(), NULL, NAME);
}

void device_init(void) 
{
    create_device();
    driver = vc_cons[fg_console].d->port.tty->driver;

    printk("Keyboard leds device Initialized");
}

void device_exit(void)
{
    device_destroy(class,  create_dev_type());
    class_unregister(class);
    class_destroy(class);
    unregister_chrdev(major_number, NAME);

    printk("Keyboard leds device exited");
}

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

That's how I'm trying to invoke it:

```
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include "src/device.h"


int main(void)
{
    int fd;

    if ((fd = open("/dev/keyboard_leds", O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)) < 0) {
        perror("Open failed!");

        return -1;
    }

    ioctl(fd, ON);
    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Code should be given in the question post itself, not through the link. See [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I just didn't want to put a mile long question here, much easier to check on GitHub.

Comment: This is just Stack Overflow works - code **should** be included into the question itself. BTW, 80 lines are not too long for kernel code. Just copy paste them into the question post and format using `Ctrl+K`.

Comment: Well, okay, I pasted it.

Comment: What **exact part** of your code doesn't work? Did your try to debug it? Does construction `driver->ops->ioctl(vc_cons[fg_console].d->port.tty, KDSETLED, led_status);` changes LED status in newer kernel?

Comment: That part in 3.16 it works perfectly, and changing the leds. In the newer version, the timer runs, the status changes, but it's like that line is ignored, or not executed properly. I couldn't find anything about it if that changed in newer kernel versions.

Comment: Normally, if some function doesn't work as expected, it returns error code. What is returned by that `->ioctl` call?

Comment: For the first time it returns 0, then -1. How could I debug it? There is nothing useful in dmesg.

Comment: On error, kernel's functions normally returns `-err`, where `err` is errno code. Code `-1` corresponds to `EPERM`. ioctl command is processed in [vt_do_kdskled](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/tty/vt/keyboard.c#L2090) function.

Comment: Thanks, that's useful, but any idea why I'm getting this error? I tried to chmod + chown the device file, or execute as root, but no luck.

Comment: Permissions are checked with [line](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/tty/vt/vt_ioctl.c#L360) `if (current->signal->tty == tty || capable(CAP_SYS_TTY_CONFIG))`. I am unsure whether `capable()` is applicable for kernel process, when callback for hrtimer fired. You may output result of `capable()` call using printf before -`>ioctl()`. In any case, access mode for **your device file** is unrelated.

Comment: I see. It returns 0 but randomly 1. I'm not sure what should I do with this.